# Kdenlive 20 doesn't render anything, doesn't save anything

Tags: linux-mint, kdenlive

I'm using

the open source video editor,
**Kdenlive Version 20.08.0** (Using: MLT version 6.22.1, FFmpeg libraries)

and trying to render a video clip. But this feature does nothing in my version. No Errors no Result as you could see here https://youtu.be/YuWPBhJpPuI

i pressing "Render to File" nothing happens. Do i have to press elsewhere? My OS is Linux Mint xfce-Desktop. Do i have install a other Liunx?

i tried it installing it via packet manager. then i tried it using the terminal like described here: [https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable)
Version via terminal looks more modern. But problem stays.

Is there a whey i do get it maybe run?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open a video file needs Minimum two steps.

Open a video file into Kdenlive. Then move the video file into the timeline. Now you are able to render the file hopefully.

Comment: Interesting, so it doesn't automatically add it in like Movie Maker.